# Choose which keyboard open with ionic/cordova without input type

Tags: cordova, input, ionic-framework, keyboard

I have a problem with my Ionic/cordova App. I have some input box with the type = "text" and i can't change it. The problem is with this type my App open the keyboard for the text, but i need the number keyboard. How can i workaround this problem?

Comment: Only way to open numeric keyboard is input type number

Comment: And i can't set it :( possible there isn't a workaround?